# Dspace Installation Error

Tags: java, maven, dspace

I am trying to install dpsace on my windows computer. I dont have a proxy and my internet connection is fast enough, i get the error :

```
BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 7.853 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-04-18T07:36:04+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 14M/50M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce (enforce-java) on project modules: Execution enforce-java of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/Joker/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-enforcer-plugin/1.4.1/maven-enforcer-plugin-1.4.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/Joker/.m2/repository/backport-util-concurrent/backport-util-concurrent/3.1/backport-util-concurrent-3.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/Joker/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.11/plexus-interpolation-1.11.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/Joker/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-jdk14/1.5.6/slf4j-jdk14-1.5.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/C:/Users/Joker/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.5.6/jcl-over-slf4j-1.5.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/C:/Users/Joker/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting-api/2.2.1/maven-reporting-api-2.2.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/C:/Users/Joker/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-sink-api/1.1/doxia-sink-api-1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/C:/Users/Joker/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-logging-api/1.1/doxia-logging-api-1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/C:/Users/Joker/.m2/repository/commons-cli/commons-cli/1.2/commons-cli-1.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/C:/Users/Joker/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interactivity-api/1.0-alpha-4/plexus-interactivity-api-1.0-alpha-4.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/C:/Users/Joker/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.3/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/C:/Users/Joker/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[12] = file:/C:/Users/Joker/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.22/plexus-utils-3.0.22.jar
[ERROR] urls[13] = file:/C:/Users/Joker/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.3/commons-lang-2.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[14] = file:/C:/Users/Joker/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/enforcer/enforcer-api/1.4.1/enforcer-api-1.4.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[15] = file:/C:/Users/Joker/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/enforcer/enforcer-rules/1.4.1/enforcer-rules-1.4.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[16] = file:/C:/Users/Joker/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-common-artifact-filters/1.4/maven-common-artifact-filters-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[17] = file:/C:/Users/Joker/.m2/repository/org/beanshell/bsh/2.0b4/bsh-2.0b4.jar
[ERROR] urls[18] = file:/C:/Users/Joker/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-dependency-tree/2.2/maven-dependency-tree-2.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[19] = file:/C:/Users/Joker/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.5.5/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[20] = file:/C:/Users/Joker/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/aether/aether-util/0.9.0.M2/aether-util-0.9.0.M2.jar
[ERROR] urls[21] = file:/C:/Users/Joker/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-i18n/1.0-beta-6/plexus-i18n-1.0-beta-6.jar
[ERROR] urls[22] = file:/C:/Users/Joker/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugin-testing/maven-plugin-testing-harness/1.3/maven-plugin-testing-harness-1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[23] = file:/C:/Users/Joker/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-archiver/2.2/plexus-archiver-2.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[24] = file:/C:/Users/Joker/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-io/2.0.4/plexus-io-2.0.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[25] = file:/C:/Users/Joker/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.11/junit-4.11.jar
[ERROR] urls[26] = file:/C:/Users/Joker/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------: begin 0, end 3, length 2
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
```

Comment: Have you JDK 9? Google turns up for version 1.4.1: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MENFORCER-275

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It looks like you are trying to setup DSpace 6.x on a machine with JDK9 (or more precisely JDK >= 9).**

DSpace 6.x isn't compatible with Java 9. **Please install JDK8 instead.**

[The docs say](https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC6x/Installing+DSpace#InstallingDSpace-JavaJDK7or8(OpenJDKorOracleJDK)):

> ### Prerequisite Software
>
> ...
>
> Java JDK 7 or 8 (OpenJDK or Oracle JDK)

[Here's an older thread](http://dspace.2283337.n4.nabble.com/mvn-problem-td4685757.html) on DSpace support forum, it mentions a different problem, but is also related to DSpace lacking support for JDK9.

Comment: happy to help ;)